# hide mouse with batchfile

Tags: windows, batch-file, hide, mouse

Hi i want to make a batfile that looks something like.

```
hide mouse
run /wait some.exe
show mouse
```

the issue i have is i am making a arcade cabinet. and i have a few games that do not hide the mouse pointer and it just sits dead center on the screen. 
This isn't usually an issue as you can just move the mouse and hide it, but as its an arcade cabinet there is no mouse..

I have tried and app that hides the mouse pointer after a few seconds. but that causes other issues "it will often minimize the game when it hides the mouse" I could probably use AHK to force the window IF it happened. but that seems like a lot more work than just having a bat file for the few games that i wish to hide the mouse on..

this is the windows mouse pointer.. not an in game specific mouse.

Comment: `cmd` on its own isn't even aware of a mouse. You need some external utility (from the internet or self-programmed). Maybe *moving* the cursor "out of sight" is an alternative, when *hiding* it causes problems.

Answer (score 0):

given stephans's message i decided to use a seriese of batch files to kill the mouse hider app when the aplications it minimized start and then retart the app when those tasks end..

I was hoping for a more elegant solution but it seems to be the only way i can do this.

given it is now mostly AHK scripts being used to call bat files im not sure if i need to delete the question.

the process is possible to do in batch but for my needs it was better to run the bat from a ahk script as this kept it as elegant as possible.

for any one else..

```
the AHK reads. 

run %rompath%pin.bat
Runwait, %rompath%%romname%%romextension%

ExitApp

;Required

CloseProcess:
WinKill, A
run %rompath%pinst.bat
return
```

pin.bat reads:

```
taskkill /f /im "AutoHideMouseCursor.exe"
```

and pinst.bat reads:

```
start "path to exe\AutoHideMouseCursor.exe"
```

The app i used to hide the mouse is AutoHideMouseCursor

if this question is best served to be deleted let me know.